# Stuck on info starting JS server

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have initiated successfully a new `react-native` project. Then, every time I try to run my newly built project using the command `react-native run-android`, it gets stucks on `info Starting JS server...`.

Here is the output:

```
$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX".
 You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 855 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server..."
```

I tried restarting the laptop and switching emulators. I don't know what else to do anymore.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: i found a way around it, i had to close the auto server that opens to allow the react-native cli to skip awaiting the launch of the js server and then i started it manually

Comment: I have same issue. I found that `npm run android` will stuck on VS Code terminal, but its normal on system terminal (I'm using GNOME terminal).

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Kill the automatically popped up metro bundler command prompt

Kill the command terminal which is running `react-native run-android`

Now Run `react-native start` This will start your js server

In new command prompt window run `react-native run-android` 
The app came up in 5 mins in an emulator.

Comment: But this is a temporary solution, do you know how to run `react-native run-android` without run `react-native start` first?

Comment: I haven't tried anything after this.

Answer (score 24):

**Linux:**
Go to the terminal and type:
`react-native start`

and then in **OTHER** terminal, inside your project folder:
`yarn android`
or
`npm run android`

Comment: actually 
npm start
npm run android

Comment: That's weird, but it worked.

Answer (score 5):

Temporary fix:

```
REACT_TERMINAL= react-native run-android
```

in my case with `manjaro + xfce4`:

```
REACT_TERMINAL=xfce4-terminal react-native run-android
```

or puts in your `.bashrc`:

```
export REACT_TERMINAL=xfce4-terminal
```

font: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26097

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I started a project yesterday and it worked, started a new one today and it didn't work. The problem seems to be "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android". The version that showed up today is 2.8.2 as opposed to 2.7.0 for yesterday's project.

I used:
    `npm install @react-native-community/cli-platform-android@2.7.0`

This is not a optimal solution, but it will get you going.

Answer (score 3):

In my case(Manjaro OS)
First:

```
npm start
```

Then in a separate terminal:

```
npm run android
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same frustrating issue for a very different reason than mentioned in other answers.

As explained in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40333037/903842) Android **adb** binds to port **5037** and I installed some program which took this port so adb was hanging silently (*why adb! .. say something!*)

**Commands to test if this your issue cause:**

test any adb command and see if it hangs, eg:

```
adb devices
```

If it does, then check who is using the port:

```
sudo lsof -i :5037
```

Comment: Saved my day. My emulator (not sure why) process was running and was not even showing on the screen. After killing the process, react-native worked smoothly. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that I constantly find myself using, is going to the application manager on android, then clearing the data of the app. Running the app afterwards goes smoothly without lagging.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling android studio with a new emulator or changing the app name in **app.json , build.gradle and android manifest.xml** solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Having same issue due to react-native reanimated package
step 1: Go to visual studio, open terminal cmd/powershell
step 2: npm uninstall react-native-reanimated
step 3: cd android
step 4: ./gradlew clean
step 5: Hit enter and boom

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I run this command after install expo, expo changed my project name to another, when I decide to give up to use expo, I find it can't run android, finnaly, I change the name in package.json to coordinate to name in app.json.

Key is keep your projects name same in app.jon and package.json

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).